# How to update label once a day?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I'd like to have a label in my app that gets updated once a day at a specific time (i.e. 12 a.m.). If you could help me out I'd really appreciate it, thanks.

This is what i currently have but it only works if the app is opened between 12 and 1 am.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];

NSString *stringDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

if ([stringDate isEqualToString:@"00"]) {

NSLog(@"its working");


[self changeLabel];

}
```

To clarify, I'm trying to change the text of a label once a day. I'd like to have the label update at a specific time like 12 am so that it updates with the start of each new day. I've tried a few ways of doing this but haven't gotten the desired result. If anyone knows of a way to do this I'd appreciate your input.

Comment: Is this for MacOS or iOS?

Comment: iOS, specifically iPhone/iPod Touch

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you want a bit more, because whatever you want to do this seems like a bad approach. If you're more clear about what you want, we'll be able to point you in the right direction better.

Comment: I'd like to change the text of a label once a day at a specific time, like 12am.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to determine the last time the application was opened, you can use `NSUserDefaults` to save the date and then check that the approprate number of seconds (86400 = 1 day) have passed.

Something along the lines of the following should point you in the right direction:

```
    //gather last time app was opened
    NSDate *lastUpdated = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"app_last_updated"];

    //check date is valid
    if(lastUpdated)
    {
        //determine number of seconds that have passed
        NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [lastUpdated timeIntervalSinceNow];

        //check time interval is greater than 1 day
        if(timeInterval > 86400)
        {
            //update label
        }
    }

    //save current time
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"app_last_updated"];
```

Comment: I don't necessarily want to check when the app was last opened. I'm trying to have the app update the label each day at a specific time (i.e. 12 a.m.).

Comment: You could determine that from the code I posted using a date formatter to check if the date is after 12am. Unless you have the app running constantly, theres no way to update the label without checking the last time the app was opened.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do. On iOS, most likely your app is not running in the foreground all the time.  So I would just update the label when the application is active in [applicationDidBecomeActive:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidBecomeActive%3a).  Then I would create a timer to fire at the specific date/time I want.

For example:

```
NSDate *d = // create the next date/time
updateTimer_ = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate: d
                          interval: 0
                          target: self
                          selector:@selector(updateLabel:)
                          userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runner addTimer:updateTimer_ forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Comment: Don't forget to invalidate the timer when the app goes into the background.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but a few days ago I needed just what Dave123 asked and I came up with this solution after searching a lot on the web:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSLog(@"applicationDidBecomeActive");

    self.masterviewController = [[PBMasterViewController alloc] init];

    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    NSLog(@"Seconds --------> %.f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"OLD_DATE"]]);
    NSLog(@"old date: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"OLD_DATE"]);

    // 24 hours must elapse between each update check
    if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"OLD_DATE"]] > 86400) {

        NSLog(@"Time elapsed since last update is MORE than 1 day. Check for updates.");
        [self.masterviewController checkForUpdates];

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Time elapsed since last update is LESS than 1 day. Don't check for updates.");

    }

    // Here I convert the seconds into hours with two decimals, if you want to show the time elapsed in a UILabel
    NSString *stringCheckInterval = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f hours since last update", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"OLD_DATE"]] / 60 / 60];
    NSLog(@"%@", stringCheckInterval);


}
```

Answer (score -1):

is there someone that has the app opened form more than 24h??
Anyway, you can simply use an NSTimer with 86400 as delay time.

Comment: its not that theyd have the app open for 24 hours.  The app checks the time based on the devices native clock and then updates the timer with each new day. It has nothing to do with how long the user has the app open

Comment: I'd like to avoid using a timer with 86400 because it would reset if the user kills the app.

Comment: Misunderstanding than. use NSUserDefaults, and set last update data. At the start of your application check that value, compare to current time stamp and play with it as you like

Comment: I spend a lot of time figuring out why my timer stopped in the background, until I read in SO that NSTimer stops after 3-10 minutes working in background, unless you use an approved service like map services or external accessory. Therefore, don't waste your time with NSTimer.

Answer (score -1):

When you start the app, set up a timer that will fire at 12:00:01 AM and update your label.

Comment: how do I set a timer that fires based on the time of day?

Comment: NSTimer *time = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:<#(NSDate *)#> interval:<#(NSTimeInterval)#> target:<#(id)#> selector:<#(SEL)#> userInfo:<#(id)#> repeats:<#(BOOL)#>];

Comment: the NSDate param is the date (with time) that you need, interval will be 86400, target self selector the method you want to call. in user info put your label to refresh and set YES for repeat.